# Ant script for Maven war and deploy

Tags: maven, ant

We have a Maven project (using Eclipse/Java) that we need to create a war of, and deploy to a remote Tomcat server. We need an ant script for this.
Could anyone please share code samples or any other pointers?

Comment: Why do you need an Ant script for this?

Comment: I once do all of the tasks you list above with bash script. If that's all you're asking for, bash script (or .bat file if you are using windows) is enough

Comment: @DaveNewton You can look into it as a constraint - we can only run Ant scripts from the build side.

Comment: And why a -1? What was -1 about the question? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file like this, I called it build.xml

```
<project name="APP" default="copywar" basedir=".">

<!--=========================================================================

            Helper - Version 0.1
==========================================================================-->

<property name="dist.dir" value="target" />
<property name="tomcat.home" value="YOUR TOMCAT DIR" />
<property name="deploy.dir" value="${tomcat.home}/webapps" />
<property name="website.name" value="APP.war" />
<property name="websitedir.name" value="APP" />

<!-- Undeploys the web site from tomcat -->
<target name="copywar" depends="">

    <delete dir="${deploy.dir}/${websitedir.name}" />
    <delete file="${deploy.dir}/${website.name}" />

    <echo message="Deleted directory and War" />

    <!--Copy web application to deplyment dir -->
    <copy file="${dist.dir}/${website.name}" todir="${deploy.dir}" />
</target>
```

And on your pom.xml you need to add

```
<!-- copyToTomcat with build.xml -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>package-ear</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <ant target="copywar" inheritRefs="true">
                                <!-- Here, connect with build.xml -->
                            </ant>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you tell what you mean by <!-- Here, connect with build.xml --> - sorry totally new to Maven/Ant world.

Comment: Also I can understand the copy to deploy dir part - but in which step will the war be created?

Comment: Also will just running the ant script do both 1. generate the war and 2. copy it to the deploy location?

Comment: it's a comment that tells you where is the connection between maven and ant. when you do a clean install, the .war is copy to deploy dir. Try to run the clean install, you can se that after the war is generated, it copy to the deploy dir